# Sum by logical condition, in a dataset with groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

[image]

I want to transform the continuous `Age` variable into a discrete one, that is equal `a` if the original was between 1 and 2, and `b` if it was betweem 3 and 4. Thus needing to aggregate the values of `Value 1` and `Value 2` by summing the entries associated with `Age`=1 + `Age`=2  and `Age`=3 + `Age`=4. The output would be something like this:

[image]

The `146` is the sum of the `Value1` entry for `Age`=1 (75) and `Age`=2 (71).

I thought on using aggregate:

```
`df2 = df %>% group_by(Sex, Race) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Value"), fun))
```

Where `fun` would be some function that checks the `Age` values and sum accordingly. But i'm not much familiar with these dplyr functions and couldn't get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Data:

```
df = structure(list(Sex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2), Race = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2), Age = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4
), `Value 1` = c(75, 71, 52, 51, 24, 21, 70, 58, 67, 68, 36, 
22, 91, 43, 33, 57), `Value 2` = c(22, 22, 49, 1, 20, 18, 34, 
0, 27, 37, 31, 83, 29, 24, 10, 99)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to do the recoding of 'Age' based on the values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Race, Age = case_when(Age %in% 1:2 ~ 'a',
                      Age %in% 3:4 ~ 'b')) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#    Sex  Race Age   `Value 1` `Value 2`
#* <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1     1 a           146        44
#2     1     1 b           103        50
#3     1     2 a            45        38
#4     1     2 b           128        34
#5     2     1 a           135        64
#6     2     1 b            58       114
#7     2     2 a           134        53
#8     2     2 b            90       109
```

---

Based on the OP's comment, if the original data have lots of categories, an easier option is `cut` or `findInterval`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Race, Age = cut(Age, breaks = c(-Inf, 
       seq(0, 90, by = 5), Inf), labels = letters[1:20])) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks! In my actual dataset, age goes from 0-90, and i want to group it by 0-5 ~ a, 6-10 ~ b, 11-15 ~ c, etc. Is there a way to create all those groups in a less space consuming way than listing them all inside `case_when`?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro you can use `cut` or `findInterval`.  updated the post